# Strip string from beginning and up until literal w/ PHP

Tags: php

In the example below, I'd like to removing everything up until (but not including) `<!--more -->`. Not very familiar with PHP string functions.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat`<!--more -->` at vero
>   eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
>   zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber
>   tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming
>   id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem
>   insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.
>   Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt
>   saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur
>   mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera
>   gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum
>   formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem
>   modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in
>   futurum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a string-functions-only method (no arrays or regex)

```
$newstring = substr($oldstring, strpos($oldstring, "<!--more -->"));
```

**Edit** Didn't notice the "up to by NOT including" in the OP, and had removed the delimiter string `<!--more -->`. Fixed to leave it in.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and use the first part:

```
$parts = explode('<!--more -->', $your_string);

print($parts[0]); // will print what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat<!--more --> at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.';

$sub = substr($str, strpos($str, '<!--more -->'));
echo($sub);
```

http://ideone.com/P95NZ

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into an array using `<!--more -->` as a delimiter.

```
$array = explode('<!--more -->', $str);
echo $array[0]; // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... dolore eu feugiat
echo $array[1]; // at vero eros ... sollemnes in futurum.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This regex is untested.  It might need a little tweaking for special characters

```
preg_replace('/[\w\s]*<!--more -->/i','<!--more -->',$string);
```

Comment: Why would you use regex for this (definitely not needed)? Regex is *much* more expensive than native string functions.

Comment: Because I think a single line solution makes more sense.

Comment: Most other answers here are single line (including my own) and are much less expensive than this. Regex should only be used when absolutely needed.

Comment: @Demian What's the actual performance difference between your solution and the regex?  How often does he need to be running this for that to be even remotely relevant to user experience?  I'm sure you have the numbers handy on that, since you seem so certain.

Comment: Take a look at any number of benchmarks that are available on the interweb. You're right- it's not relevant to user experience, but why write inefficient code when there's a better option that's just as easily written (not to mention more readable)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum...';
$pos = strpos($string, '<!--more-->');
$newstring = substr($string, $pos); // Everything from <!--more-> onwards
```